# Regex bypass some punctuations from text

Tags: python, regex

I have a text like this:

```
text = 'hello, how are you?'
```

I want to extract `hello, how` from the text,

```
re.search('hello how', text)
>>> None
```

If you are thinking why I am not giving the comma because I am getting the text which I want to extract from some other text as the input regex and this input regex **does not** have punctuations while the text has. So, I want regex to  bypass the punctuations for example to bypass `,` after the `hello`.

```
_________________________                 \     ______________________________________
| Input Regex           |      ------------\    | Text from which I have to extract  |
| (Does not have puncs) |      ------------/    | (have punctuations)                |
| For ex. (hello how)   |                 /     | For ex. (hello, how are you?)      |
_________________________                       ______________________________________

The output of the search should look like
>>> 'hello, how' (the output should have punctuations)
```

I cannot simply remove all of the punctuations from the text like 'hello, how are you?' as it may contain some essential punctuations which I cannot delete. I want regex only to bypass the `,` after the `hello`.

The input regex and the text can be anything, one more example:

```
input_regex = 'Google LLC'
text = 'Google, LLC. is an American multinational technology company.'
# so the output should be
>>> 'Google, LLC.' # with punctuations
```

So is there any way to bypass these punctuations without deleting all the punctuations from entire `text`. Thanks!

Comment: If you can't come up with strict rules about when to keep the punctuation and when to toss it, then your problem cannot be solved.  There's no magic here.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I know that. But I thought that might be some way out which I may be unfamiliar with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If keeping any and all punctuation and spacing (so everything which is not a number or letter) is fine, then you can just use `[^\w]*` between/after the words you search for.

```
match = re.search(r"Google[^\w]*LLC[^\w]*", text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I split words and find input start with the same text.

```js
function deepSearch(input, text) {
  const [chunkInput, chunkText] = [input.split(' '), text.split(' ')];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < chunkInput.length; ++i) {
    if (!chunkText[i].startsWith(chunkInput[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could automatically modify the search pattern by allowing a comma before each space, i.e. when searching for `Google LLC` you seem to actually want to search for `Google,? LLC`.

The question mark in RegEx means "zero or one occurrence".

A simple solution could be:

```py
def searchWithOptionalCommas(needle, haystack):
    needle = needle.replace(' ', ',? ')
    return re.search(needle, haystack)
```